# Redirect not working in ReactJS using Navigate inside Delete request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the function where I am calling delete, here navigate to '/' is not working, please help me

```
const deleteClick = async (_id) => {
  try {
    const url = API_URL;
    // Make the delete request using axios
    const response = await axios.delete(url);
    console.log(`Deleted post with ID ${_id}`);
    // Navigate only after a successful deletion
    navigate('/');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error deleting blog:', error);
    // You might want to handle errors or show a message to the user here
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share your complete code repo or host it on sandbox?

Comment: https://github.com/varungole/Blog-MERN

Go to frontend --> src --> components --> Geography.js
There, you will find deleteClick() function